# WPF set menu height to fit?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

In WPF, how can one set the height of menu to fit , instead of like this below where the gray shade goes down
[image]

```
<Window x:Class="XAML_Concepts.GridLayout"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="GridLayout" Height="600" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Menu IsMainMenu="True" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="1" >
            <MenuItem Header="File">
                <MenuItem Header="_New"></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="_Open"></MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>

            <MenuItem Header="Edit"></MenuItem>

        </Menu>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I just need it to look a **normal menu**, like one in windows explorer, without any gray shading below. I have tried manipulating row size, menu size, and several other attributes but I' missing something simple.

When I set the Grid''s row height to , say 20px , this is what I get which I am not pleased with because A-I don't want to enter an absolute height and B-The shade doesn't look right, it is like the background gradient is smearing..
[image]
Thanks

Comment: where is the grey color coming from?

Comment: I didn't set the color, it is the default color

Comment: The problem is that the implicit value for `Height` in `<RowDefinition/>` is `*`, which is equivalent to `1*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

This will cause the first row to shrink to only as much space as is necessary to display the content.

Answer (score 3):

You must set the height of the row that your menu is located in to `Auto`. Like this:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

When a row or columns width or height is set to `Auto`, it only takes as much space as it needs.